# Getting the n best elements from a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, data-structures, stl

I have a vector of structures, for which I have overloaded all comparison operators for. I do not know the size of the structure at compilation time.

What's the fasted way to retrieve the n best (where "best" can be either the smallest or the largest) elements in the vector? I am aware of max_element and min_element but they only return a single element. I would prefer to not loop n times, retrieving the best element, removing it and then getting the next one. This approach seems too slow.

Thanks.

Comment: Sort the vector then read the top and botton _N_ elements?

Comment: `std::partial_sort` or even better `std::nth_element`

Answer (score 6):

You can use `std::nth_element`, that will move the smallest `n` elements to the first `n` positions in the range (notice that the relative ordering of those `n` elements is not defined).

```
std::vector<T> objects;
std::nth_element( objects.begin(), objects.begin() + n, objects.end() );

// Now the range [objects.begin(), objects.begin() + n) contains the lowest n elements
// Obviously n must be <= objects.size()
```

When you write that you do not know the size of the structure at compilation time, I assume that you have a collection of polymorphic objects, and you have a vector of pointers instead of elements. No big deal, you can still use `std::nth_element` with a lambda.

```
std::vector<T*> objects;
std::nth_element( objects.begin(),
                  objects.begin() + n,
                  objects.end(),
                  [](const T * lhs, const T * rhs)
                  {
                      return (*lhs) < (*rhs); // Or (*lhs) > (*rhs) for the greatest n elements
                  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Sort it and take n first elements.

```
struct Foo { };
std::vector<Foo> v = { Foo(), Foo(), Foo() };
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());

std::vector<Foo> v_best(v.begin(), v.begin() + n); //where n is your best count
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach than the brute-force sorting-and-taking-the-first: Set up a temporary container of size `n` and initialize it with the first `n` elements of you original vector (which has size `N`, say). Sort that temporary vector.

Next traverse your original vector and insert elements (using `std::lower_bound`) whenever they are larger than the current minimum of your sorted container (and at the same time, throw out the current minimum). This should first take `O(n log n + N)` instead of `O(N log N)` asymptotically, but more important, also the constant prefactors are likely much smaller.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve the `n` smallest elements sort the `vector` in ascending order.

If you want to retrieve the `n` largest elements sort the `vector` in descending order.

Then,

1. Get two iterators.

   ```
   start = v.begin();
   end = start + n;
   ```
2. Iterate from `start` till `end` but excluding `end`.

Comment: And If don't want to sort?

Answer (score 0):

The other answers here work, but you could also use [copy_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy).

```
std::vector<int> vec{ 1, 5, 7, 9, 3, 6, 8, 4, 2 };

std::vector<int> odd;
std::copy_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::back_inserter(odd), [](int a){ return a % 2 == 1; });
std::vector<int> low;
std::copy_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::back_inserter(low), [](int a){ return a <= 3; });
std::vector<int> high;
std::copy_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::back_inserter(high), [](int a){ return a >= 7; });
```

There is also [remove_copy_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove_copy) if you need to remove the matching data.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it.  How does this copy the 10 best elements, when you don't know the values in advance ?

Comment: `copy_if` copies values in the range given into a specified vector, and takes in a predicate of what to copy (I passed in that predicate here in the form of a lambda expression).  So you would just define that predicate (function) of what "best" would mean.

Comment: it's not the first n good ones, but the n best. Can you please show us the lamda you would use to select the 10 biggest elements ?

Comment: @Christophe you are right, looking at this now, it isn't a great solution for what he wants.  As I read his question, I was reading "best" as undefined and min and max being more of an example.

Answer (score 0):

I propose you a **solution that does neither modify nor make a copy of the vector**:

So I assume that the original vector is very very big and you still need the data in the original order for other purposes

```
template <typename T>
set<T> best_n2(vector<T>& v, size_t n)
{
    set<int> u;          // the result is a sorted set
    int i = 0;
    for (auto x : v) {   // fill the N first elements
        if (i++ < n) {
            u.insert(x);
        }
        else if (x > *u.begin()) {  // then get rid of the smallest if necessray
            u.erase(*u.begin()); 
            u.insert(x);
        }
    }
    return u;
}
```

*If you can modify the original vector, I'd choose the solution of szulack.  I didn't propose it because he types much faster than I do ;-)*